# How to redirect a URL to open in puffin browser instead of safari browser in ios app?

Tags: objective-c, swift

As like we use this to open URL in facebook app. I want to open URL in puffin browser.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://"]]) {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/355356557838717"]];
}
else {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/DanielStormApps"]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
            let urlPath: String = "puffin://www.facebook.com"

            let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)!

            let isInstalled = UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url)

            if isInstalled {

                print("Installed")

            }else{

                 print(" Not Installed")
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'puffin://' to open URL in http. Or use 'puffins://' to open URL in https.

Answer (score 0):

Add infoplist file

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

You are open that type url :[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb://profile/355356557838717"]

Comment: i want to add this kind of thing for puffin browser